# magento 1.9.0.1 after appling supee-6788 customer register not working

Tags: supee-6788

I just applied supee-6788 to my magento store running 1.9.0.1.

The customer registration not working, after submitting the information, page reloads with empty data. Customer login works fine.

I tried to put

`<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />`

in the

```
/app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
```

and

```
/app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
```

still not working, and error log show nothing.

Also, I reverted the patch, the problem gone. looks like the problem is from SUPEE-6788,

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, after turn on the template hints, it show the register page is using opc, add form_key to register.phtml, it works fine.